# 500 error when trying to use the MAIL function

Tags: php, email, iis, error-handling

We just migrated our PHP 5.2 / IIS 8 website to a new server.

We are unable to use the MAIL function.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

that returns:

> the 500 error

1. How do I enable detailed error messages?
2. is there something I need to install to get the `mail` function to work?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: have you checked mail settings in php.ini since you changed server?

Comment: @user2014429 make that into an answer and ill mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default PHP uses sendmail, You need to configure your PHP setting to use a SMTP server on windows.

The link below will get you started...

http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/31/sending-email-from-php-on-windows-using-iis.aspx

Comment: Ideally you'll want to use the SMTP server of your hosting provider or ISP. Running your own SMTP server is much more of a pain in the ass than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

500 is a permanent smtp error and therefore there is either a problem with the configuration of the mail server or the recipient of the email.

If you telnet to the server on port 25 and issue the following commands;

```
helo localhost
mail from:<your.email.address>
rcpt to:<recipient.email.address>
data

ctrl c
```

What happens?